# is it possible using jquery in xul?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, firefox-addon, xul

I want to create a popup to display the results of the application process is done, I want to use jquery.

I want to ask whether it is possible to use jquery in xul?

if it possible, how to insert a result of the function you want to display?
if it's not, is there any function in xul which can create appearance look like using jquery?

Comment: From what I've seen in other questions in SO, you can use jQuery with xul

Comment: 30 seconds google search turns up: http://digitalmihailo.blogspot.com/2008/05/jquery-and-dynamic-html-in-xul.html

Comment: This has been asked on SO a few times. Search for `[firefox-addon] jquery`. I also recently discovered [jquery-xul](http://www.imaitech.com/jquery-xul/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is javascript. XUL is javascript along with the other stuff. So, yes, but I'm not sure what you would gain by that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
 <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://myapp/content/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>
```

but if you want manipulate dom, then you can simply use js example

```
        var row = document.getElementById("row01");
        row.setAttribute("class","todaylo");

        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.setAttribute("value",loanofficers.lo.loname);
        row.appendChild(label);
```